# Запуск Service при уничтожении Application

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.

Такой вопрос: есть Application, которое состоит из Service и Activity, как перезапустить Service, например, когда Application уничтожено с помощью диспетчера задач? Есть догадки, что можно как-то перезапустить, используя BroadcastReceiver, но как, не знаю.

Comment: Руки за такое отрывать надо )

Comment: за что именно? ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже написано в комментах, делать такое **очень** не рекомендуется, т.к. пользователи ожидают, что оператива будет очищена от приложения, когда они его убивают. Если же оно убивается системой, то тоже не просто так, а чтобы освободить ту же оперативу. Если перезапускать сервис или активити при этом, то памяти будет не хватать и какая-нибудь игруха тяжёлая у пользователя будет падать. Не надо так.

Если всё же хочется быть злым и вообще нехорошим, то пропишите старт сервиса в, например, **onDestroy()**. Не уверен, что сработает в этом месте **startService()**, а вот посылка своего сообщения своему ресиверу, стартующему сервис, через, например, **LocalBroadcastManager** наверняка сработает.

Или сделайте **AlarmManager**, коий будет каждый **n** минут/ секунд проверять, крутится ли сервис и, если нет, стартовать его.

Главное помнить, что это плохо-плохо-плохо.

Comment: onDestroy апликейшена никогда не вызывается

Comment: @gcoder, я имел в виду метод активити или сервиса. Они, насколько я помню, вызываются.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не так это плохо, как вы пишете. большинство гугл сервисов работают именно так (не убиваются).     
Я рекомендую способ с AlarmManager. Т. к. onDestroy() вполне может и не вызваться, если процесс будет убит системой.